# snowplow java script tracker setup : collector URI

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, snowplow

I'm trying to setup snowplow tracker. I'm facing the following issues

1.The healthcheck test is not working(In scala stream collector -running step)

> error- connection refused, 404 error

2.Setting up tracker 
Below is the code given in GitHub for snowplow setup
In that what is collector URI, there are example for scala stream collector, examples are given only for cloudfront.

```
<!-- Snowplow starts plowing -->
<script type="text/javascript">
;(function(p,l,o,w,i,n,g){if(!p[i]){p.GlobalSnowplowNamespace=p.GlobalSnowplowNamespace||[];
p.GlobalSnowplowNamespace.push(i);p[i]=function(){(p[i].q=p[i].q||[]).push(arguments)
};p[i].q=p[i].q||[];n=l.createElement(o);g=l.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];n.async=1;
n.src=w;g.parentNode.insertBefore(n,g)}}(window,document,"script","//d1fc8wv8zag5ca.cloudfront.net/2.5.1/sp.js","snowplow"));

window.snowplow('newTracker', 'cf', '{{MY-COLLECTOR-URI}}', { // Initialise a tracker
  appId: '{{MY-SITE-ID}}',
  cookieDomain: '{{MY-COOKIE-DOMAIN}}'
});

window.snowplow('trackPageView');
</script>`enter code here`
<!-- Snowplow stops plowing -->
```

Comment: Did you replace the bracketed strings with the appropriate values? `{{MY-COLLECTOR-URI}}`, `{{MY-SITE-ID}}`, `{{MY-COOKIE-DOMAIN}}`

Comment: no I am asking what is the collector URI, What sholud be given in that place

Comment: What type of collector are you wanting to use? Cloudfront?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [snowplow tracker initialization docs](https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow/wiki/1-General-parameters-for-the-Javascript-tracker-v2.0). They explain all the parameters:

```js
snowplow("newTracker", "(any name you want)", "(your collector uri)", {
  appId: "cfe23a",
  platform: "mob"
  cookieDomain: null,
  cookieName: "_sp534_",
  encodeBase64: false,
  respectDoNotTrack: false,
  userFingerprint: true,
  userFingerprintSeed: 6385926734,
  pageUnloadTimer: 0,
  writeCookies: true
});
```

If you need help setting up a Scala Stream Collector, you can [read here](https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow/wiki/Setting-up-the-Scala-Stream-collector).

If you need help setting up a Cloudfront collector, you can [read here](https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow/wiki/Setting-up-the-Cloudfront-collector).